# ci zip encoding class not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to crate a zip file and download it.
So my code is as follow;
Since i am using ci zip encoding class

my folder structure is like
    c:/xampp/htdocs/gallery/print/oid_1/1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg

My code

```
$path = getcwd().'/print/oid_1/';
$this->zip->read_dir($path,FALSE);

// Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
$this->zip->download('oid_1.zip');
```

Here is my problem,

l C:\Users\instinctclassic\Downloads\Compressed\oid_1.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged so what does this means -does it means it was mistaken while making zip file or it was mistaken while downloading.For downloading mistake i have downloaded the zip file many time enough to be sure.
2 I repaired the downloaded zip file(oid_1) and extract it but the extracted folder structure is not ignored before the oid_1 folder as said in ci zip encoding class tutorial

```
 $this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE); 
 //This will create a ZIP with the folder "directory" inside, then all sub-folders stored correctly inside that, but will not include the folders /path/to/your.
```

3 Assuming my folder oid_1 already exists somewhere on server.

I know this question is previously asked but mine exist all the problem from making zip file to extracting.So i am sorry for this.
Thanks

Comment: try to check your zip file content with text editor, maybe you'll find something usefull

Answer (score 0):

Try directory path like this:

> $path = getcwd().'\print\oid_1\';

this way path will be proper, because getcwd() will return you c:\xampp\htdocs\gallery

Comment: $path = getcwd().'\print\oid_1\'; it will be already an error in netbeans

Comment: sorry use \\ in the end like : $path = getcwd().'\print\oid_1\\';